# How to implement a service that can output formula with tex parameters?

Tags: php, image, tex

Is there some open source project I can refer to?

I'm using PHP.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried about half a dozen of the available solutions. The best I've seen is [QuickLaTeX](http://www.quicklatex.com/) which has a WordPress plugin which could easily be adapted to other platforms. It has better vertical alignment than the other solutions. There is a list of most of the available solutions at http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?p=59

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [LatexRender](http://www.mayer.dial.pipex.com/tex.htm) might do what you want.

Comment: Have you tried? It only requires two files (the site says), where one actaully wraps latex in a class, and the other contains a convenience function.

Comment: No,it need to install several other softwares

Answer (score 1):

Download the Wikipedia engine and analyze how it renders formulas.

That's a general "how do I implement..." solution: remember where you might have met the feature you're looking for, then download the sources and use them/their ideas.

If you're looking for a pure PHP script that renders TeX -- you'll fail: no one dares to implement a script of that complexity. Even if you find one, it won't support all the nice packages provided by the TeX community!

All solutions use command-line TeX builders. *NEVER* invent bicycles until you're sure your bicycle has a chance of becoming the best ;)

Comment: I think it's a general rule that if you're looking for a pure <insert non-C language here> way to render TeX - you'll fail. Every method I've seen of rendering TeX uses TeX under the hood.

Comment: Which is also the point, no?  All tex renders the same, regardless of where

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mimetex](http://www.forkosh.dreamhost.com/source_mimetex.html) and its variant [mathtex](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html).

Answer (score 0):

There's a service that was implemented with mathtex:

http://www.forkosh.dreamhost.com/mathtex.cgi?\sum_i^N%20\lim_{x%20\rightarrow%20k}x

Answer (score -1):

Sure there is one good service or project avaiable. 
Its a latext implementation written in pure php have a look ;-)

The code is very clean and logical

**[LATEX PHP](http://github.com/timhunt/Moodle-Question-Engine-2/blob/2f223338fb4c9f7e807fd9b07fd7c0837dce8e44/filter/tex/latex.php)**

Comment: This is not pure PHP: it uses `latex` engine as a backend.